# Роз'яснення щодо "вторий"

Tags: словотворення, архаїзми

Чому є досить часто вживане слово "вторинний" (у знанні "другорядний"), але немає "вторий" (у знанні "другий", навіть як застарілого, в словниках не фіксується). Яке походження слова "вторинний"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> у знанні *другий*, навіть як застарілого, в словниках не фіксується

Занотуйте, що наступного разу було би непогано указ[ув]ати які саме словники. Але можу погодити ся, що во̂дсутня сама стаття або згадка в будь-яко̂й статте̂ во̂ ве̂домих мене̂ словниках, наприклад в: СУМ-е̂ [11](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) і [20](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85), [словнице̂ Грінченка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_(%D0%93%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)) ітд. При цьому СУМ-и мають *втора*, але знов ж таки не як чисто *друга*:

> [ВТО́РА](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=16758&page=560), и, *ж*.
>
> 1. Другий голос у музичній партії.
> 2. Друга скрипка.

А також, хоч і з припискою *розм.*, але ве̂домо про [*первий*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pervyj).

Ось етімолоґія во̂д [ЕСУМ-а](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) *вторинний*, там ж згаданий і *вторий*:

> [ВТО́РА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
>
> - псл. vъtorъ‹*ṇtorъ, *ṇterъ;
> - споріднене з лит. añtras «другий, інший», лтс. ùotrs, прус. атtars, двн. andar, гот. anþar, oc. œндœр, дінд. antarah «тс.», іє. *ontor-/ *ṇtor-;
> - з другого боку, припускається звʼязок з ав. vitara- «далі», дінд. vitarám «тс.», vítaraḥ «той, що веде далі» (Фасмер І 364–365);
> - російська *вто́ра, второ́й* «другий», білоруська *уто́ра*, давньоруська *въторъ*, польська wtór, болгарська *вто́ри* «другий», македонська *втор(u)*, старословʼянська *въторъ*;
> - Фонетичні і словотвірні варіанти: *втора́к* «другий рій», ***вто́рий***, ***втори́нний***, *втори́ти*, *второвки́* «другі струни на кобзі або бандурі», *вторува́ти*, *повто́р*, *повтори́ти*, *повто́рний*.

Тож можна вважати, що в *одному словнику* є згадка слова. Однак, на жаль, наразе̂ поки не можу во̂дпове̂сти, чому гинші ве̂домі словники не мають.

Во̂д себе зазначу, що [*во̂второк*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) теж має того ж корня *втор*.

Щодо вжитку, то слово *вторий* було вживане [Шевченком](https://zaxid.net/n1252476) і [Скороводою](https://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/3662/196/151922/)<sup>1</sup>, Франком<sup>2</sup> ітд, гинші приклади вживу є в корпусах [Ґрака](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac15&keyword=%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9&showresults=1) і [Лайпціґа](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9). Можна також згадати ве̂дому сучасну пе̂сню Пирятина — [Арта](https://genius.com/Piryatin-arta-lyrics)<sup>3</sup>. Щоправда, часто приписують до суржику:

> В. С. Єгорова: [«Культура мовлення сучасної молоді»](https://www.dnu.dp.ua/docs/zbirniki/ffil/program_56d3512b75eb5.pdf)
>
> – «українізовані» форми російських числівників: первий, перва, вторий, втора, сєм, пятий, восім, чьотири, шесть, девять;

> [Тиждень](https://tyzhden.ua/Culture/233955)
>
> Викладачка англійської та аргентинського танго Світлана Ємець найперше пригадує багатовимірне «тю», «балакаю», «вторий» та «калідор». Суржик використовує хіба що для гумористичного ефекту, проте походження з Полтавщини все одно наклало відбиток на все життя, через що кілька разів у мандрах незнайомі люди вгадували, звідки вона приїхала.

Або все ж таки до діялекто̂в, наприклад того ж по̂втавського:

> <sub>Л. А. Москаленко [«Акти (протоколи) полтавського полкового суду»](https://movoznavstvo.org.ua/index.php?option=com_attachments&task=download&id=319) (1683-1750 pp.) — памʼятка української мови</sub>
>
> Порядкові числівники, утворені від назв одиниць, десятків, сотень і тисяч,
> переважно не відрізняються від сучасних українських літературних або діалектних форм: … *вторий* …

Також є така згадка:

> <sub>М. Протасов. [Об упорядочении и унификации античной транскрипции](https://r2u.org.ua/node/54) (1940)</sub>
>
> І. Огієнко твердить, що написання *фт* замість *θ* «знаходимо часто у наших письменників XVI – XVII віку», а про поширеність вимови *θ* як *фт* свідчать Полтавські акти 1666 – 1667 р., де нерідко замість *вторий* (-ый) писано *форий*.

---

1. Скоровода — дещо, як на мене, спеціфічний приклад.
2. Див. дале̂ згаданй корпус Ґрака.
3. Обережно, є непристойна лексіка.

Comment: Дякую за роз'яснення, досить вичерпна відповідь!